# Could 'dark' energy just be ordinary photons?

Tags: cosmology, photons, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I had this idea a while ago that dark energy might just be ordinary photons 'building up' in the recesses between galaxy clusters and giving rise to the expansion of the universe. I know that the universe's expansion is also accelerating, and I feel that this might be explained by the cosmological constant acting in addition to this effect from ordinary photons building up between galaxies. Basically, the question I wanted to ask; in light also of recent experiments wherein it's been proven that laser light can trap atoms; whether or not ordinary photons from galaxies might, in effect, be trapping and manipulating galaxy clusters into moving away from one another rather than there being any more-mysterious form of energy behind that expansion.

Comment: so what makes you think that these photons are 'dark' as in undetectable?

Comment: Well, they would just be bouncing around in between galaxy clusters. The atoms in the galaxies forming the clusters would be reflecting the photons and they wouldn't be going near any instruments that would make them detectable. That's sort of what I thought.

Comment: The number of hidden photons needed to account for dark matter is just too large. Wait did you meant dark energy or dark matter?

Comment: Besides the other problems mentioned, the sign is wrong. More photons would mean more deceleration of expansion, not acceleration.

Comment: @SamCottle In order for photons to keep reflecting between galaxies, it has to somehow always hit a galaxy and not escape the cluster.

Comment: As much as I am sympathetic to the arguments that dark energy is a terrible misnomer, it's not *such* a bad name that the dark energy is actually a form of light energy. (Others here gave the scientific reasons why.)

Comment: @zucculent Not necessarily. I was thinking that some would escape to the extremities of the universe but that the photons 'building up' between clusters would have been emitted since the universe began, has anyone here (@Mauricio?) done a calculation for exactly how many photons that would be?

Comment: Can you clarify where this photons that are "building up" are coming from?

Comment: @SamCottle, if you think that is possible then you you will have to come up with some serious argument as to why photons are not reaching us and why we have a day and night cycle. Remember that the whole of matter is estimated to be 5% while dark matter is estimated to be over 25%. This fact alone (if its true) seems to me that the whole universe would be way more brighter than a supernova explosion all the time, if the 70% where made of photons as you claim. Non of the Radio/Optical observations that we have made would ever be possible.

Comment: @zucculent from galaxies, galaxies emit photons.

Comment: @TheImperfectCrazy I'm not sure I agree with you on that, to my mind it seems more likely that galaxies would be reflecting the photons back into regions of intergalactic space.

Comment: @SamCottle when you look at a dark patch of night sky, you are probably looking at space outside our galaxy. If your eyes were sensitive enough, you could see the other galaxies. TheImperfectCrazy's remark is: if photons coming from other galaxies can reach your eyes with no problem, why should these dark energy photon be reflected before reaching Earth? Both kind of photons come from outside the galaxy, but photons from other galaxies don't get reflected. We see them. So we should see a **lot** of "dark energy photons", if they were real

Answer (score 2):

Dark energy made of photons is excluded by any measurements of the cosmological parameters. We know that the energy content of the universe is about 30% matter, only about 0.001% radiation (photons and relativistic neutrinos) and about 70% something that we call dark energy and that behaves in a very different way from photons. For instance, it has negative pressure.

If that 70% were made of photons instead, universe would look very different.

There are many independent measures (more or less precise) of the percentages I have just given: primordial elements abundance, barion acoustic oscillations, cmb anisotropies, age of the universe, Ia supernovae. Look them up!

Comment: I think may be worth adding that light in a vacuum always moves at the speed of light in a vacuum, orders of magnitude faster than anything else in the universe is moving relative to its neighbors. If dark matter was made of photons, it would have become basically uniform at this point.

Comment: I'm not talking about dark matter.

Comment: @SamCottle I think it is a typo. zucculent probably meant dark energy

Comment: Seeing as though the cosmological constant and the fact that space is thought to emit photons (via the creation and annihilation of photon-antiphoton pairs), and that this notion is closely related to dark energy, it seems that the tendency in physics is to think about dark energy in terms of photons already. No other particle(s), so far as I'm aware, have been proposed as candidates for dark energy. In the study of dark matter, by contrast, there are proposals for new particles.

Comment: @SamCottle "No other particle(s), so far as I'm aware, have been proposed as candidates for dark energy" - I was not aware that the photons had been proposed as dark energy candidates. Why do you think they have? Where have you read it?

Comment: @Prallax https://www.newscientist.com/definition/dark-energy/ this article explores the different, current, theories of dark energy. What I was referring to was the vacuum energy notion associated with 'dark energy'.

Comment: @SamCottle The vacuum energy comes from virtual particles, not real ones (**and from any particle, not just photons**). The difference is crucial, because virtual particles can't go bouncing around in clusters, but must annihilate shortly after being created

Comment: Yet, if the vacuum energy is associated with dark energy at all then dark energy must be photons since we've detected the vacuum energy (i.e. in experiments confirming the Casimir effect) as photons. This is going round in circles.